# Trying to implement ldap search in my asp net core app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, ldap

Trying to implement ldap search in my asp net core app but i know only the domen, login + password and uid. I've got a message from the ldap owner's that looks like that:

```
ldapsearch -x -D “***-ldap-access- -W -H ldaps://"url" “uid=ЛОГИН_СОТРУДНИКА»
```

But when trying to do that i don't understand what do i need to fill in the "??"

```
static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()  
  {  
     // create and return new LDAP connection with desired settings  

     DirectoryEntry ldapConnection     = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://examplestudent.university.ru");  
     ldapConnection.Path               = "LDAP://OU=??,DC=??,DC=??,DC=??";  
     ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;  
     return ldapConnection;  
  }
```

Please help me figure that out

Some more implementation forms, didnt work out.

Comment: Why don't you use this overload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-directoryservices-directoryentry-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-string)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're going to use that `DirectoryEntry` in a `DirectorySearcher` to make a search.

You're already setting the `Path` by passing `LDAP://examplestudent.university.ru` to the constructor here:

```
DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://examplestudent.university.ru");
```

Setting the `Path` again will overwrite that. So you can delete this line:

```
ldapConnection.Path               = "LDAP://OU=??,DC=??,DC=??,DC=??";
```

Then you just need to decide which path you want to pass to the constructor, which depends on your requirements.

If you use `LDAP://examplestudent.university.ru`, the search will return results from the entire domain.

If you use something like `LDAP://OU=whatever,DC=...` then then search will return results from only that one specific OU. If that's what you need, then you need to give it the `distinguishedName` of the OU, which will be something like:

```
DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Users,DC=examplestudent,DC=university,DC=ru");
```